# module not found: cannot resolve web3 cannot resolve truffle-contract

Tags: webpack, blockchain, solidity, truffle, web3js

when I run the command `npm run dev` it gives me this error , I tried several times to install various versions of `web3`  and also truffle-contract  but it gives me same error every time.

EXACT ERROR:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascripts/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'truffle-contract' in 'C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\SID\ALSC\PROJECT\asset-lending\app\javascripts'
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.js 6:1-55
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/javascripts/app.js

ERROR in ./app/javascripts/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web3' in 'C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\SID\ALSC\PROJECT\asset-lending\app\javascripts'
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.js 5:1-39
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/javascripts/app.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install truffle-contract it solves those 2 errors, if it doesn't work try to install globally, in my case i installed locally.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract

Comment: I tried both locally and globally but still it  gives same error